# How do I disable Tripadvisor's "Just for you"?

Tags: tripadvisor

When searching for hotels on Tripadvisor, it shows me hotels ordered by "Just for you".

Is there any way to disable this, *without* logging in?

I was hoping that removing cookies would do the trick, but it doesn't — clearly there is some information stored server-side based on my IP address.